# Shift horizontal position of a field

Tags: jasper-reports

How can we make a field to shift left if the preceding field is null/empty? I have 2 fields, ZIP and City. City is placed on the same line just after Zip. I want to shift City to left if Zip is empty. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two identical City text boxes, one where it is, the other behind the Zip field. Set the `PrintWhenExpression` property in that one to (zip==null). Set it in the original to zip!=null. (All necessary $F stuff omitted for brevity.)